# PHP Regular expression help to work with Browser Agent String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm currently trying to learn regular expressions with some simple "real world" examples.

Take in consideration the following string:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT
> 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko

I want to find the RV value (1.9.2a1pre). I need to apply the following rules:

1. RV: can be in any case (RV, rv, rV, Rv...).
2. RV: can be anywhere in the string.
3. The RV: value ends with either a closing parenthesis, any whitespace (including linebreak), a semicolon or the end of string.

So far I did:

```
/rv:[.][\)]?/i
```

but it's not working (I must be far from the "true" solution)...

The expression must work with PHP [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: `/rv:([^)]+)/i` — terms to read up on: *character class*, *quantifiers*, *capturing groups/subpatterns*.

Comment: You probably wanted to include whitespace in the square bracket.

Comment: @Frank, it was a nudge for the OP not an answer hence being a comment rather than a real answer posted ⇩ down there. I left out "here's a starting point", and any real explanation, for the sake of brevity (and as a continuing social experiment to see if the answers below picked up on not quite fulfilling the spec, or just copied and pasted; on that note, I was well rewarded). Apologies if you took it any other way.

Comment: I assume you are aware of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

It does not appear to capture the RV value. Its related so I thought I'd post it. HTH.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware :) RV value is only good for the (very) early Mozilla browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/rv\s*:\s*([^;)\s]+)/i
```

will match `rv`, followed by a `:` (which may be surrounded with whitespace), then a run of characters other than `;`, `)` and whitespace (including newlines). The match result (after `rv:`) will be captured in backreference no. 1.

Comment: It's working with my all test cases (I have several hundreds). Oli version woks too /rv:([^;)\s]+)/i any one "better"?

Comment: Well, this version also accepts tabs and newlines to end a match, as you specified. Other than that, they are pretty much identical.

Comment: Your version is perfect but how would I add this rule to your regexp: ":" (for "rv") can be leaded & followed by an optionnal space (so the match can be "rv:" or "rv: " or "rv :" or "rv : " in any character case.

Comment: OK great I get it now :) Just one last question: why don't you wrap your \s with [] (like Oli)? I guess it's redundant, but why?

Comment: You need brackets if you want to group *several different* characters into one logical unit. `[abc]` means "one of a, b, or c" - `[a]` is the same as `a`. Sometimes a single-character-class makes sense for readability: `^[ ]*` looks nicer to some people than `^ *`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my revision to allow the RV sub-string to be anywhere

```
/rv:[\s]*([^); ]+)/i
```

- `()` denotes the capture group (ie, what you want to get back from this process)
- `[^); ]` means characters that are *not* `)`, `*space*` or `;`
- `+` means one or more times
- `*` means as many as you like, 0-many.
- `[\s]*` just before the parenthesis basically means we chop off any leading whitespace from the match, essential in this case because we're explicitly saying we break the main match on a space.

So this is looking to capture a string of chars excluding `)` one or more chars in length, immediately after `rv:`.

Your version `/rv:[.][\)]?/i` looks for a single `.` then optionally a `)`.

Comment: Seems to work in most cases but does it takes in consideration the end of the rv: value (closing parenthesis, semicolon, end of sting or whitespace)?

BTW I don't know why someone downvoted you :(

Comment: Your description of the original regex is not precisely correct; it looks for a single **dot** character. Your revised regex answer does not match the bulleted description.

Comment: It's now working with my all test cases (I have several hundreds). Tim Pietzcker version woks too /rv:([^;)\s]+)/i any one "better"?

Comment: @Activist: Tim's more precisely follows your description.

Comment: Tim's doesn't allow for any space after `rv:`. Eg `rv: 1.9.2.5` wouldn't match. I don't know the likelihood of that ever coming up but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `[.]` means a **dot**, not "any character" ... 
use this instead:

```
/rv:.+[\)]?/i
```

Comment: Just tried it and it does not work. Oli one seems OK except for the end of rv: value.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko';
preg_match('/rv:([^\)]*)/i', $str , $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: just tried the very same code on my local dev and the out put is:

1.9.2.a1pre

so it should work fine - perhaps a bit more of your code may help us help you?

Comment: Yes but the rv: value can also end with a ; and your regexp dont work in these cases (see point #3 in my question).

Answer (score 0):

may be :

```
/rv:([^); \n]+)/i
```

that means NO ) ; space line-feed one or more time case insensitive and captured

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
(?<=rv:).*(?=\))
```

everything within parentheses is a group. this `?<=` is called a positive lookbehind. it basically matches a string before the string you want. this `?=` is called a positive lookahead and matches a string after the string you want. since the string you want is simply numbers, letters and a decimal or two, the `.` operator works as a catchall and matches any character except line breaks. `*` indicates one or more of the previous characters.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko';
preg_match('/rv:([a-z0-9\.])*/im', $str , $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```